# How to accept data from a frequency table in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I need help on how to get a list of data from two different inputs, a value input and a frequency input.
I think i could do it by creating a dictionary and adding the values and frequencies to it in the form {v:f,v:f,v:f} etc., but I don't know how to do that.

e.g.

values = First, enter or paste the VALUES, separated by spaces:
frequencies = Now enter the corresponding FREQUENCIES separated by spaces:

It should take each number - separated by spaces - and add it in to the dictionary
so say if
values = 1 2 3 4 5
and
frequencies = 5 4 3 2 1
the dictionary should be
{1:5,2:4,3:3,4:2,5:1}
meaning 1 appears 5 times, 2 appears 4 times, 3 appears 3 times, 4 appears 2 times, and 5 appears once.
and a list from that should be
[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5]

I tried mucking around with for loops and i think i will have to use one or two but im not sure how

Comment: input is two strings (with white spaces as separators). output is one list like [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,5]. right?

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by `Counter`

```
from collections import Counter
lst = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5]
print(Counter(lst))

>>> Counter({1: 5, 2: 4, 3: 3, 4: 2, 5: 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary = dict(zip(input('values = First, enter or paste the VALUES, separated by spaces: ').split(' '),input('frequencies = Now enter the corresponding FREQUENCIES separated by spaces: ').split(' ')))

dictionary = [k for k,v in dictionary.items() for _ in range(int(v))]

print(dictionary)   #[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5] if you input '1 2 3 4 5' and '5 4 3 2 1'
```

Comment: thank you, this seems like it could work. however, when i run the code it says there is an error that a string cannot be interpreted as an integer, and i'm not entirely sure how to fix it

Comment: I'm sorry I've forgotten that `v` is str type. I've corrected my answer now it works properly.